# Image invisible outside div element bounds

Tags: html, css, image

How does one make part of the image outside div element (in which it is contained) invisible?

For example, I have:
div.imageContainer of 200 pixels in height,
image (of circle) inside the div, 200x200 pixels,
the top half of image (circle) is inside the div.imageContainer

Currently, it is as follows:

```
div.imageContainer
{
position: relative;
}
div.imageContainer img
{
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
}
```

However, the bottom half which is outside the div element is visible and overlapping few other elements below (I'm trying to construct a test banner). How do i go about hiding the *part* of the image outside of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` inside the parent div should do the trick

Comment: At first, it totally made image invisible. But after you mentioned it again, I thought about defining the height of the div.imageContainer with height=200px; and it worked with that.